# Pipe git command to sed output

Tags: bash, git, sed

I am trying to pipe output from git to sed, which will inturn replace a value in file.config that represents the last commit on a branch.

I am unsure how to do this using piping in bash. I thought maybe something like this? But it doesnt work (outputs nothing)

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD | sed -i 's/"commit".*:.*".*"/"commit": "${$_}"/g' file.config
```

Is this even possible, or is there a better approach I can take?

Contents of file.config

```
{
    "commit" : "684e8ba31"
}
```

Contents of file.config (after running command)

```
{
    "commit" : "${$_}"
}
```

Contents of file.config (expected output)

```
{
    "commit" : "441d6fc22"
}
```

Ouput from git rev-parse --short HEAD

```
441d6fc22
```

Comment: You're both piping input to `sed` and telling `sed` to read from a file: you can't do both.

Comment: Can I put the git rev-parse --short HEAD inline within the sed command instead?

Comment: please update the question to show the output from the `git` call and an indication of what part of the `git` call is to be applied in the `sed` call; also show the current contents of the `file.config` file, and the expected changes to `file.config` (we only need to see a handful of lines from `file.config`, including the line(s) to be modified)

Comment: Changes made as requested

Comment: the standalone `sed` call appears to generate the desired changes to `file.config` soooo .... what does the `git` call have to do with any of this?

Comment: git rev-parse --short HEAD outputs a short sha of the last commit. I would like that commit value to replace the one in file.config

Comment: that's not what you've shown in the expected output; where is the actual/complete set of `git` output? what is the final content of `file.config` (corresponding to the `git` output)?

Comment: I have added those also. Does that help?

Comment: the `git` output includes the double quotes?

Comment: double quotes removed

Comment: Does `file.config` contain only those 3 lines, or is there other content in the file, which needs to be preserved? In other words, is it really necessary to use a search-and-replace approach, or is it also acceptable to simply generate the content from scratch and overwrite the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '/"commit" *:/s/: *"[^"]*"/: "'$(git rev-parse HEAD)'"/' file.config
```

will do it. You're confusing command-line arguments with stdin input. They're both good and widely-used ways of feeding the invoked program data but the differences in capacity and timing matter, so spend more time studying how they work.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for the help. I was wondering if I could do inline like that but wasn't exactly sure how to. Now I know :)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, `sed` is a general-purpose text munger, one I genuinely love and have much use and time for. `jq` is a special-purpose json munger I rarely have much use for but it's much more expressive and powerful . . . and compact. ``jq .commit=\"`git rev-parse HEAD`\" file.config | sponge file.config`` is easier to read and harder to fool when it comes to json text, you might prefer it.

Answer (score -1):

Simulating output from `git` call:

```
$ cat git.out
441d6fc22
```

One idea where we capture the `git` output to a variable and then feed the variable to `sed`:

```
$ read -r sha < <(cat git.out)
$ sed -E "s/^(.*\"commit\"[^\"]*).*/\1\"${sha}\"/" file.config
{
    "commit" : "441d6fc22"
}
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `(.*\"commit\"[^\"]*)` - (1st capture group) everything from start of line up to and including `"commit"` and then everything that follows up to the first occurrence of a literal `"`
- `.*` rest of line
- `\1\"${sha}"\"` - replace with contents of 1st capture group followed by literal `"`, contents of `sha` variable and another literal `"`

Once satisified with the result the `-i` option can be added:

```
$ sed -Ei "s/^(.*\"commit\"[^\"]*).*/\1\"${sha}\"/" file.config
$ cat file.config
{
    "commit" : "441d6fc22"
}
```

Pulling original `git` call into the mix:

```
read -r sha < <(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
sed -Ei "s/^(.*\"commit\"[^\"]*).*/\1\"${sha}\"/" file.config
```